# what is if [[ ! $1 =~ ^# ]]; in unix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am reading a shell script in Unix.
I have come upon the below line:

```
if [[ ! $1 =~ ^# ]];
```

I understand the part which is on left side of equal sign but what does `~^#` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression the `=~` is:

> `<STRING> =~ <ERE>    <STRING>` is checked against the extended regular expression `<ERE>` - `TRUE` on a match

So the `^#` is a extended regular expression. Since `#` is not a special character in extended regex. The meaning of the if checks that the string in `$1` does not start with `#`. So on the command line

```
$ if [[ ! '#' =~ ^# ]]; then echo matches; else echo no match; fi
no match
$ if [[ ! 'b' =~ ^# ]]; then echo matches; else echo no match; fi
matches
```

Answer (score 1):

- The `~` allows to use POSIX regular expression matching ([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)).
- The `^` is a special character that evaluates the beginning of a line

In your case, `^#` means a line beginning with `#`. Then your condition only takes care of **lines that do not begin with `#`**.

In shell scripting, lines beginning with `#` are comments, that are not evaluated as commands by the `shell`.